# ReactJS header tags in different pages

Tags: reactjs, seo, meta-tags

I am pretty new to react, and I have several pages I want to have different header content in. For instance, my index.js page has another title than my contact.js, and also meta information as well.

I thought I solved this problem by installing react-meta-tags, where I have put my content like this:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( 
            <div>
                <MetaTags>
                <title></title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                <meta name="copyright" content="" />
                <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
                <meta name="author" content="" />
                <meta name="description" content="" />
                <meta name="keywords" content="" />
                </MetaTags>
                <Header/>
                <Experience/>
                <Projects/>
                <Contact/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work, even though a numerous of Google searches, people claimed that the Google bots were smart enough to catch this. You see, when I search up my own page on Google, it just displays my website URL (typically for websites with no title), and it also tells me that my website is not mobile friendly, which it is. And when I click the link, or go to my page directly - it shows up perfectly responsive.

If I put this code in my index.html file, it all seems to work perfectly. The only problem I have then, is that I will only have one title, and the same keywords on all of my pages. How can I fix this?

I'm not sure, but I am pretty certain that this will hurt my SEO. Even though I have everything working, it doesn't really matter as long as Google doesn't recognize important content like the meta tags I have listed.

Comment: 'react-document-meta' seems like a better library to add meta tags. Check it out.

Comment: @raksheetbhat I checked that out, but I couldn't seem to use it properly. So with some Google searches, I tried another two plugins - one of them called react helmet. It works perfectly when I visit the website, but when I do a SEO check on my website, it still says that title and meta tags are missing. Could this be due to the fact that Helmet is server-side, and therefore gets rendered after the static HTML content and therefore has a 'delay' and that might be why Google (?) and other SEO checkers won't regognize it?

Comment: Yes, you're right as mentioned here: http://www.brombone.com/what-is-the-javascript-seo-problem/, which says, "These frameworks are using the browser to build the actual content of the page. When Google crawls your site, it just reads the raw pages. It doesn't open them in a browser and it doesn't run the javascript. So, it doesn't see the content, it just sees an empty page."

Comment: @raksheetbhat I see. But there has to be some kind of fix for this? I mean, reactJS isn't one of the most popular JavaScript frameworks for nothing?

Comment: You're right. I guess one way to go would be to try a few more components till one of them works :\. I wish I had a better answer. Here's a discussion on the same question: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/recommended-way-for-setting-head-information-for-a-page/297/3, which suggests 'react-document.title'. Hope this one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

React helmet is in my experience the better choice.
When it comes to SEO you should get all the data that crawlers care about to be rendered serverside. What you could do to speed up the troubleshooting is to view the page source of you page instead of the markup after all client-javascript has run. This way you can see your pages as the crawlers do and determine if the markup is correct.
Be aware of that search engines do not catch changes in your pages instantly, these pages need to be crawled and indexed before new changes are shown (this can take some time).